# Redirect many images via 301 htaccess / php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

An image gallery has 120,000 images. I want to change URL such as this:

```
/album_mod/upload/8c3d534a1451c87aca1fa710be6be8.jpg
```

to this, using a 301 redirect with a .htaccess file:

```
/image/gallery/category-a8/imagename-i6282.jpg
```

However, my problem is that the original URL has no ID in the URL. My idea is to:

1. Make a redirect for all JPG files to /redirect/
2. Create a index.php in /redirect/
3. Cut of with php the filename for example "8c3d534a1451c87aca1fa710be6be8"
4. Select in the DB for "8c3d534a1451c87aca1fa710be6be8".
5. Take the category and the image name.
6. Build the new string like:

```
/image/gallery/category-a8/imagename-i6282.jpg
```

In this way I have two 301 redirects. Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried any htaccess rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do invisible rewrite to `.php` with this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^album_mod/upload/(.+)\.jpg$ /redirect/index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

And after that you can do only one 301 redirect, with the right new name.

Comment: can you help me with this one also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739423/stop-image-hotlinking-with-whitelist-htaccess