# Stop image hotlinking with whitelist htaccess

Tags: regex, image, .htaccess

A big image galerie need a hotlinking script with a whitelist for google, bing, yahoo etc.
On the web I found many examples but they have all a different syntax.

Example 1:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?google/.*$ [NC]
```

Example 2:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google\. [NC]
```

Example 3:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google. [NC]
```

Example 4:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^(http|https)://.*google.*" whitelist
```

Example 5:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?google/.*$ [NC]
```

*Question 1: Which one is the fastest and correct with a domain wildcard?

Question 2: Why is on example 5 a http:// infront when its not needed?*

**What I did**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !my-domain\.                   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !search\?q=cache               [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !google\.                      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !twitter\.                     [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !facebook\.                    [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !googleusercontent\.           [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !bing\.                        [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !pinterest\.                   [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !yahoo\.                       [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/hotlink\.jpg$               [NC]

RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://domain.tld/hotlink.jpg  [R,NC,L]
```

*Questions 3: Is it faster to have only 1 line? How can I write it such as this*:

```
google|facebook|bing|etc
```

What I did:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !my-domain\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(google|googleusercontent|yahoo|bing|facebook|pinterest|etc.) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/hotlink\.jpg$               [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://my-domain.tld/hotlink.jpg  [R,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well not really scientific but my guess is the ored option would be longest.

I did a try on http://www.regex101.com with this regex: `(google|googleusercontent|yahoo|bing|facebook|pinterest)` to match `http://www.yahoo.com`

It took 87 steps (you can see it in regex debugger on the site) where it tooks only 7 steps to match with a regex which is `yahoo`

So roughly 7 by 9 (number of RewriteCond) give 63 steps where the ored regex took 87 steps, so I think it would be faster in any case using simple regex and multiple RewriteCond until the steps cross (the regex will took a predictable number of steps, try it with the full ored and the last match to know the maximum steps).

Once again: nothing scientific there and myabe it would take more time calling 9 test than a complex one, maybe a apache in debug mode could tell the time taken but I'm unsure.

It's still a matter of choice to prefer one over the other, as I'm quite sure it won't do a noticable difference before the serer has stalled anyway by the number of requests.

---

For the match the `domain\.` is enought, no need to use something more complex in my opinion, maybe you may got some edge cases where there's `domain.` elsewhere in the referer...

The `\` before the dot is important to match a litteral dot and not any char after `domain` in the regex.